# element book: validity error : Element book content does not follow the DTD

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, docbook, sgml

I have the following DocBook structure in my book.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"  "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.1.2/docbookx.dtd" 
    [ <!-- -->
   <!ENTITY bookinfo SYSTEM "bookinfo.sgm">
      <!ENTITY abstract SYSTEM "abstract.sgm">
      <!ENTITY chap1 SYSTEM "chap1.sgm">
      <!ENTITY biblio SYSTEM "biblio.sgm">
      <!ENTITY the_author "Author Name">
    ] > 
    <book> 
      <title>Book title</title>
     &bookinfo; 
      <abstract>
        <para>Abstract.</para>
      </abstract>
     &chap1; 
     &biblio; 
    </book>
```

When I am running `xmllint -valid book.xml` from cmd, I am getting this error:

> book.xml:18: element book: validity error : Element book content does not follow the DTD, expecting ((title , subtitle? , titleabbrev?)? , bookinfo? , (dedication | toc | lot | glossary | bibliography | preface | chapter | reference | part | article | appendix | index | setindex | colophon)*), got (title CDATA abstract CDATA CDATA )

Why does xmllint give me this error? Seems everything is OK...

Comment: It is hard to reproduce as we don't know what is in `&bookinfo`, i.e `bookinfo.sgm` but most likely is that it opens and closes a `<bookinfo>` block. Probably `<abstract>` is now at an invalid place (should be in an info type of block, se also: https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.0/abstract.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the external parsed entities referenced in the document (bookinfo.sgm, chap1.sgm and biblio.sgm) are at their correct locations and valid, the validation error is caused by the presence of the `abstract` element in the `book` element.

For the list of parents of `abstract`, see ["abstract" in *DocBook: The Definitive Guide*](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/4.5/abstract.html).

You can solve the issue by moving the `abstract` inside an element where it is allowed. For example, if `bookinfo.sgm`  is defined as follows, book.xml will validate:

```
<subtitle>The Subtitle</subtitle>
<bookinfo>
  <abstract>
    <para>Abstract.</para>
  </abstract>
</bookinfo>
```

I don't know what else you have in `bookinfo.sgm`, but moving the abstract inside a `bookinfo` element definitely works and is valid.